# Android Studio 0.6 "Select modules to import" error

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to import [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/) into my `Android` application. I've done this successfully in the past. This morning, I updated to `Android Studio 0.6`, updated my `buildToolsVersion` to `19.1.0`, and updated gradle. When I try to import the `Volley` module, and navigate to the location of the `Volley` folder in my file system, I get the following message **"Select modules to import"**.

I then opened the `build.gradle` folder in `Volley`, and updated the gradle and build version, but still got the same error. Anyone running into this issue?

Comment: Android Studio 0.6 is not the latest version. Maybe you can try to update to Android Studio 1.2.2 and see if it fixed your issue. Android Studio 0.6 was a development version before the first stable release (1.0).

Comment: I m having same issue could you find the ansver ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473822/unable-to-add-andengine-extentsions-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved it's self when updating to the latest build of Android Studio.

Answer (score 3):

I've met a problem like yours and I solved it by commenting line `#android.library=true` int file `project.properties`.It works for me and I hope it works for you or anyone else.