# unable to add andEngine Extensions - module

Tags: android, module, andengine

I have added andEngine to my project as a module, but I could not able to add box2d extentsions.

I have tried these ways. 
`project structure > import module` and it says `"select modules to import"`.

So, I tried to add it manually. I have added code to settings.gradle and build.gradle.

It says

> "Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found." and this
>   "configuration with name 'default' not found"

I am sure about my folders are correct. I tried every combinations.

What should I do?

andEngine and extentsions
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich

[Android Studio won't let me import SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734779/android-studio-wont-let-me-import-sdk) ( same error while trying to add with project structure )

Comment: Here you have another solution.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42350465/7594337

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download SDK from here for Android Studio https://github.com/mutexkid/andengine-androidstudio

Comment: Thanks that was what i wanted for a while