# Importing AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension-GLES2 in Android Studio 1.5

Tags: android-studio, andengine

I'm trying to make flappy bird equivalent app using `AndEngine`. I'm having trouble importing `AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension-GLES2` module in Android Studio 1.5

So far, I have imported `AndEngine-GLES2` as module by

```
Project Structures -> green + sign on left top -> import Eclipse ADP -> selecting path
```

to `AndEngine-GLES2` source.

For some reason when I try this for `AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension-GLES2`, it doesn't recognize it as module therefore I can't import it. I'm not using JAR FYI.

step 4 in [here](http://www.makethegame.net/android-andengine/how-to-setup-andengine-with-android-studio/) doesn't help as I can't import `AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension-GLES2`, at all.

Comment: Wonder if you can take anything from this - http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/flappychick/#1 - their tutorial is amazing. It has info on setting up AndEngine with Eclipse, but might be able to point you in the right direction with Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove "-GLES2" from folders names.

[image: Here is a picture from my folder]

Other solution could be: File -> New -> Import project -> Select AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension and save the project.
Then import the module from project structure...

Answer (score 0):

For both libraries do the following:Go to project strukture -> modules-> button + import module from existing sources.

Then click on your module, switch to dependencies bookmark and add Andengine and physics extenstion imported modules. 
Then click on Andengine project and add dependency to Physics extension module.